# Buggy simple function for binary search (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, g++, binary-search-tree

I wrote a simple function for binary search, but it's not working as expected. I have a vector with 4000000 32-bit ints. Usually, when I search for a number, if it's there, it's found and the index is returned, if it's not, -1 is returned (the index always corresponds to the value, but that's not the point).

While messing around with the program I found out that it can't find 93 (even though it's there), obviously, there must be more values it can't find.

I use CLion, which implements GDB as the debugger and G++ as the compiler.

```
template<typename T>
int BinarySearch(vector<T>& vec, T& request)
{

    int low = 0;
    int high = vec.size() - 1;

    while (low < high)
    {
        int mid = (low / 2) + (high / 2); // Styled it this way to avoid overflows. 
// This looks like where the bug happens, basically low and high both 
// become 93 while mid becomes 92,
// it then exits the loop and returns -1 because low is not lower than
// high anymore.

        if (vec[mid] == request)
        {
            return mid;
        }
        else if (vec[mid] < request)
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else if (vec[mid] > request)
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }

    }
    return -1;

}
```

I'm pretty confused by this, what's wrong?

Comment: Isn't the high boundary exclusive? E.g. T high = vec.size();

Comment: Save yourself some development time and use:  `std::binary_search`, `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound`.  They have been thoroughly tested.  Don't rewrite the wheel.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Even though I never used them, I know of their existence. I didn't mean to reinvent the wheel, just experiment a bit.

Comment: I'm sure that there must be an edge condition due to rounding of the index values. Have you learned the high art of debugging, yet, where you use a debugger, or stick statements all over the place that dump relevant data, for analysis? If not, you should consider investing some time in acquiring some basic debugging skills. It sure would be faster to do that, and be able to quickly locate one's own bugs, rather than wait for someone on stackoverflow.com who has the time to look for bugs in someone else's code.

Comment: If you were to work it out by hand, you would discover that 92/2 + 93/2 is, indeed 92. And it should be 92, because that's how integer math works. Therefore, you must then figure out what is the problem with your logic.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I used gdb, the problem happens to be that, even though I assigned mid low / 2 + mid / 2, it still gets 92, it should be 93, I looked up on the internet, but using (low/2 + low%2) + (high / 2 + high % 2) isn't working, std::round() is not working either

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I saw your comment just now, sorry

Comment: @SamVarshavchik then how can I make it round as a human would do?

Comment: Your problem is not `round()`. You're working with integers. You should be using integer math. This task does not need  floating point math, just to compute the index values. Just consider what happens when the vector has only one value. `vec.size()` is 1. Your initial `low` is 0. Your initial `high` gets set to 1-1, or 0. The `while` loop never gets executed. You will always return -1, even if you search for the sole value in the vector. Your problem isn't rounding. Your problem is a broken algorithm.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I see

Comment: You are confusing indices and values. `low`, `high` and `mid` are indices. They should be of type `int` or (better) `size_t`. They have nothing to do with `T`.

Comment: @n.m. You're right, I'm gonna fix this, but I only tried calling the code with <int> for now

Comment: If you need the average then just calculate the average: mid=(high+low)/2; However overflow would be inevitable if high is too high. You can do it this way too: mid=high/2+low/2+high&low&1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Condition should be `while (low <= high)`.
If you keep it as `while (low < high)`, then when `low==high` (means we reach the final element), while loop will break and will return -1. So,your program wont check that element.
Also you should use `mid=low+(high-low)/2;` to prevent overflow and access all values.
Problem in your code is that suppose when low=high=1, it will give mid =0(due to data conversion), which is wrong.

Comment: Not working, searching 93 makes it get stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: Worked!! Thanks!

Comment: wait, for some reason high surpasses the value it is first assigned, the problem has to be mid=low+(high-low)/2, but why? I tried searching 5000000 and it finds it, even though the vector consists of only 4000000 elements. Why is that?

Comment: Oh wait, the problem began after changing the loop from while (low < high) to (low <= high)

Comment: what do u mean by "i tried searching 5000000 even though it contin 4000000 elements"?. In binary search u search for a value not a index

Comment: isnt it itpossible to hve the number 5000000 in 4000000 elements.

Comment: yes but the vector contains all numbers from 0 to 4000000

Comment: It's a test, to generate the vector I did "vector<int> vec;" and then "for (int i = 0; i < 4000001; i++) { vec.push_back(i); }"